# How to create a while loop in python

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

I need to create a code that returns the following situation. A date range with only month and year using while and exporting it to a text file using Pandas

I created the first while but I need to add a second one that adds a year each time the month reaches 12:

```
mnst=6
yrst=2010
mned=12
yred=2020

while mnst<=mned:
    print(mnst,"/",yrst)
    mnst + 1
```

Comment: You're not changing `mnst`. It should be `mnst += 1` or `mnst = mnst + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a generator function:

```
def iterate_ym(yr, mn, yred, mned):
    while (yr, mn) <= (yred, mned):
        yield (yr, mn)
        mn += 1
        if mn > 12:
           yr += 1
           mn = 1

for yr, mn in iterate_ym(2010, 6, 2020, 12):
    print(yr, mn)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I'll put into my code. Thanks